# Why does javascript onchange event only work in first modal from a data table

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

Hello and I thank you for taking the time to read my question.

This is my first post, I have tried to be as comprehensive as possible and follow the expected requirements of posting!

**My set up**

I have a data table populated from a mysql database, each row has an 'Edit' button.

The 'Edit' button opens a modal with the data from the row. This all works correctly.

In the modal form, I have a 'select' dropdown element with an 'onchange' event to trigger a message.

**The issue**

From within the first modal (opened from the first table row's 'Edit' button) the 
 message is triggered no problem - in the modal window linked to the first row.

But if I click on any other row's 'Edit' button to launch it's modal - and then I change the 'select' dropdown value, the message is not displayed - as if the javascript function is not being processed.

**My Research so far**

Having spent time googling and searching through Stack Overflow, I think the problem could be related to non-unique IDs or Class Names - and may be they should be different for each record row?

I tried to implement this by generating ID names and Class Names dynamically by using the row's ID number - so each modal had it's own unique ID for the 'select' element - but this did not fix the issue.

I am also thinking it could be a cache issue where the script is holding on to old data, but it does not matter if I click the first row on the first time, or if I click the first row after clicking several other rows before it, it is only the first row which successfully processes the onchange event.

**My files**

---

**index.php** (to display the data table and 'Edit' buttons)

```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <th>Fruit ID</th>
        <th>Fruit Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['fruitID']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['fruitName']; ?></td>
            <td>
            <a href="#edit<?php echo $row['fruitID']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
            <?php include('button.php'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**button.php** (the modal content with 'select' element and message div)

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="edit<?php echo $row['fruitID']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="row">
        <div>
            <select class="mySelector" id="mySelector" name="mySelector" onchange="show_value()">
                <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
                <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

**script** (at the bottom of button.php to trigger the message)

```
<script>    
function show_value() {
        selected_value = document.getElementById("mySelector").value;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Selected value is "+selected_value;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: You have the same `id="mySelector"` in every modal. IDs are supposed to be unique. `getElementById("mySelector")` will just select the first one.

Comment: Hi Barmar - thanks for your comment. As mentioned, I did try dynamic IDs so each 'select' had a unique ID  like this `id="<?php echo $row['fruitID']; ?>` but this did not fix the issue

Comment: Did you change `show_value()` so it knows which selector to get the value from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass your ids as parameters as shown below. Since you already have a unique id from $row['fruitID'], you can just append that number to each id so that they will be unique too.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit<?=$row['fruitID']?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div>
                  <select class="mySelector" id="mySelector<?=$row['fruitID']?>" name="mySelector" onchange="show_value('mySelector<?=$row['fruitID']?>', 'result<?=$row['fruitID']?>')">
                      <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
                      <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                      <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
                      <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
              <div id="result<?=$row['fruitID']?>"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>    
  function show_value(input_id, output_id) {
    selected_value = document.getElementById(input_id).value;
    document.getElementById(output_id).innerHTML = "Selected value is "+selected_value;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: OK @Nosajimiki - I just noticed you suggested passing the parameter IDs to the modal ID and result message ID - not just the Select element ID. This does appear to be working - many thanks - I am just checking if it will work OK for other functions / validations I need to process inside the modals - but I think you may have found the solution

Comment: Sorry, I was missing a few closing </div> tags which may have messed things up.  Also, certain special characters or value collisions in your fruitID could cause issues, but as long as you're using an auto-incremented key integer from your database as I'd assume it is, this should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the select element value easily...

```
<script>    
    function show_value(e) { // e param is the event
        selected_value = e.value; // use e.val to get the event target value (in this case the select element value)
    }
</script>
```

be patient while i'm trying to process the best way to display the value

Comment: For this to work you need to change it to `onchange="show_value(event)"`

Comment: I have gotten used to the frameworks as some of them do it automatically but that is 100% correct @Barmar

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of jQuery `.on()` or `addEventListener`, which automatically pass the event as the parameter. But if you use `onXXX` you have to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the current id in javascript by just using this.id here is an example

```
<input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" name="username"  onchange="formhelper(this.id)">
```

now in your function you can use this id as you like example

```
function formhelper(currentID)
{

  consolele.log('the current id is ' + currentID);
}
```

you can also make the id dinamically using the php tags using this example

```
id="<?= $value['id']?>"
```